# Do you know what set these go to?

Tags: set-identification

These are more dark grey than green. Maybe from a jet or alligator or crocodile? [image]!

Answer (score 2):

[Wedge 6 x 2 Right with Reptile Skin, Red Eye, White Teeth Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41747pb019)

[image]

[Wedge 6 x 2 Left with Reptile Skin, Red Eye, White Teeth Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41748pb019)

[image]

These two wedges appear in [The Batboat: Hunt for Killer Croc](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7780-1)

[image]

[Wedge 4 x 4 Triple with Stud Notches with Exo-Force Circuitry Pattern (Sticker) - Set 7705](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48933pb007)

[image]

As name suggest this piece comes in [7705 - Gate Assault](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7705-1)

[image]

[Wedge 4 x 4 No Top Studs with Two Red Arrows on Dark Bluish Gray Background Pattern (Sticker) - Set 7256](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47753pb005) in your picture has incorrectly applied sticker.

[image]

Again, set is described in the name - [7256 - Jedi Starfighter & Vulture Droid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7256-1)

[image]

The last item depends on the color, it is either [Windscreen 10 x 6 x 3 Bubble Canopy Double Tapered with **Light Bluish Gray** Jedi Starfighter Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50986pb003) and is part of [single set](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=50986pb003&in=S).

[image]

or [Windscreen 10 x 6 x 3 Bubble Canopy Double Tapered with **Dark Bluish Gray** Jedi Starfighter Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50986pb001) which appear in [3 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=50986pb001&in=S).

[image]

Since you got a wedge piece from 7256 it is highly likely the canopy is from the same set.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Those parts are from different sets. The wedges at the top left have only appeared in [The Batboat: Hunt for Killer Croc](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7780-1#T=P)

That set does not contain the other parts in your picture.

Comment: Thank you very much!